# Java Running Program

Tags: java

this is a very simple program.
I have created a new class, and I ami going to define a new method to recall next in a new class.

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 1;
        public void showSomething(){
            System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
        }

    }
}
```

But, when I run this program I encounter an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
```

Comment: showSomething() need to be defined **outside** of main()

Comment: What do you want the code to do? You've got a method inside another method. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is because you are declaring a method inside another method here it is `main()`.

change this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 1;
    public void showSomething(){
        System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
    }

}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 1;
    showSomething(); // call the method showSomething()
}
public static void showSomething(){
    System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
}
```

Also `showSomething()` should be declared `static` since `main()` is `static`. Only `static methods` can be called from another `static method`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle sorry for the mistake. Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a method into a method.

Do it like this :

```
public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 1;
    showSomething(number);
  }

  public static void showSomething(int number){
    System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClass().showSomething();
}

public void showSomething(){
        int number = 1;
        System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this (define the method outside the main),

```
public class MyClass {


    public static void showSomething(int number){
            System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 1;
        showSomething(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a method inside your main. 
Instead do like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showSomething();//this calls showSomething

    }

    public void showSomething(){
        int number = 1;
        System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
    }
}
```

In your class you have a main method that runs the program. On the same level you have the other methods or variables you want to use in the program.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 1;
        showSomething(number
    }

    public void showSomething(int number){
        System.out.println("This is my method "+number+" created by me.");
    }
}
```